# reading file.txt line by line put every line in different jlabel

Tags: java, swing

Im try reading file.txt line by line and outputting  every line  in different jlabel
or outtputting every line in JTable

```
 line1 in JLabel1
```

and line2 in JLabel2 ....etc

or  line1 in Row1
and line2 in Row2 ....etc
 can anyone give me an idea and thanck u all

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    linenumber++;

    label1.setText(line);
    System.out.println("line" + linenumber + ":" + line);
}
```

Comment: Better might be a JList, but your question would benefit greatly by showing us your best [mcve] attempt to solve this, then telling us your **specific** problems and asking a much more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

to add the txtuploaded into JTable :

```js
String col[]={"the title"};
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(null,col);
tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(col);
table.setModel(tableModel);
```

```js
   if (aa== JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            try {
                 file= filechooser.getSelectedFile();
                 in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file-));
                 String line = null;
               while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    linenumber++;
                   
                      tableModel.addRow(line.split(", "));
                   
           System.out.println("line" + linenumber + ":" + line);
                }
                filereader.close();
```